# Automatic Javascript Video Pop-Up

Tags: javascript, video, popup

I need a video to automatically pop up, ideally in a lightbox. It needs to automatically pop up when a user first visits the page, play the video then close. I also need a button to play again if needed. I also only want this video to play the first time a person visits the homepage, so when you navigate back to the homepage it will not play again.

Comment: People usually get paid for this type of work. Looking for help is one thing, looking for someone to write your code for you is another.

Comment: i was not looking for someone else to write my code, i was just wondering if there is a onestop solution...thx anyway

Answer (score 1):

Diodeus has a good point. The stack overflow community is to help specific questions, not to write programs for each other.

You have a number of needs, and I will try to help you sort them out:

- Embedded Video
- Lightbox
- Automatic Popup
- Stored State

**Embedding** videos can be a challenge. Quickly searching TheGoogle (embed a video) gives me this link:
http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Everything_You_Ever_Needed_To_Know_About_Video_Embedding

I did not read it, but the point is you can find many resources for video embedding.

**Lightbox**
There are many lightbox scripts ( http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/ ), you will have to slog through them to find one that you like.

**Automatic Popup**
If you're using jQuery I would suggest the [`jQuery.ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function.

**Stored State**
To see if a user has visited the homepage before, I would suggest setting a cookie.
 http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Comment: thx for your input...i know how to embed a video and how to use many of the lightbox variants out there...now i just need to get the automatic popup and the stored state thing working...i will look into your suggestions, THX again